# Updating expressions on form such as Dlookup when data has changed

Tags: ms-access

I am working with Access 2010, and what I am trying to do is connect two fields in a form together.  The first field is a combo box (`TypeCombo`), the other is a text box (`PeriodText`).  What I need to happen is when the user selects an option from the TypeCombo, it will fill in the PeriodText with the correct period.

From what I have seen the easiest way to do this is use the =DLookup function, provided.  Which is giving me the issues.  My current code for DLookUp is:

```
=DLookUp("[Type_Name]","Type"," [TypeCombo] =" & [Forms]![Form1]![TypeCombo])
```

My current code for the combo box is:

```
SELECT Type.Period_ID AS Expr1, Type.Type_Name AS Expr2
FROM Type
ORDER BY Type.Type_Name;
```

So what is suppose to happen is when the select the type I need to be able to get the `Period_ID`, then in the text box I want to use the `Period_ID` to select the correct period.  When the form loads it will give me the Expr1 of the first item in the list, but then when I change it it will not update.

How do I get dlookup to update with new data from a combo box?

Answer (score 1):

In `TypeCombo`'s `AfterUpdate` event:

```
Me.Requery
```

This updates all the queries and dlookups etc. that are used in the controls.

Answer (score 0):

E Mett, I want to thank you for your response, but I found another that works just as well for me and does what I need.  I understand how yours is suppose to work, but when I tried coding it I could just not get it to work for me.

What I ended up looking at is the focus control for my text field.  I used the first column of the Combo box and supplied that into a dlookup, I then was able to set the text of the field when ever it changes.  I know that it will not show up automatically, but in the end I still get the correct information to save.  This is what I ended up doing:

```
Strg333 = Me.TypeCombo.Value
VarX = DLookup("[Period.Period]", "Period", "[Period.Period_ID] =" & Strg333)
If PeriodText.Locked = True Then
PeriodText.Locked = False
End If
PeriodText.Text = VarX
PeriodText.Locked = True
```

I have the lock in there so that no one can change any values, its a design idea that I may end up just removing.